# Why can't I see the previous unix commands?

Tags: terminal-server

When I connect to my VPS through terminal and I want see the previous commands I get:

```
$ ^[[A^[[A
```

(by pressing up arrow)

What is wrong with it ? How can I see unix previous commands instead ?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are most likely using `sh` rather than `bash` or some other shell that allows command line editing. Try running bash and see what happens. If this fixes things for you then you will need to change the default shell for the account e.g.

```
usermod -s /bin/bash YourLogin
```

Comment: @lain how can I switch shell and use the other one ?

Comment: `chsh` also works to change the login shell.

Answer (score 1):

There is another pitfall if you have multiple shells open on the same user account: the history finally saved in the .history file will be that of the *last* shell closed.

Comment: This is true by default, but not by necessity -- see `shopt -s histappend`. (Note that bash won't see the history of other instances until history is reloaded, but you can stuff `history -a; history -n` into your `PROMPT_COMMAND`.)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can still use sh vi mode to get the command history:

```
set -o vi
<ESC> to get in command mode, K to go up the history.
```

Comment: I don't think this is a bourne shell feature. I'm not sure.  Bash certainly has it, google suggests ksh does too. Solaris sh does not, neither does dash.  So I would not rely on it being available in all situations.